# Python Kivy: How to centre a BoxLayout that's inside of a GridLayout whilst still being scrollable. In Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Kivy program that I'd like to be scrollable. I have a couple of BoxLayouts, like this,

```
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.minimum_size
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': None}
                
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1  # Light gray color
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        radius: [20,] 

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.minimum_size
                    spacing: 50
                    Label:
                        text: 'Square 1'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                        font_size: 40

                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 2
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: self.minimum_size
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        width: self.minimum_width

                        Label:
                            text: 'Label 1'

                        Label:
                            text: 'Label 2'

                        Label:
                            text: 'Label 3'

                        Label:
                            text: 'Label 4'
```

inside of a GridLayout,

```
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 50
```

that's inside of a ScrollView. I thought that adding the `pos_hint: {center_x: 0.5}` would make it align to the center, it doesn't. How would I make it align to the center on the x-axis. I've tried using a AnchorLayout but that makes the boxes stack on top of eachother.